# My First F# program

Tags: f#

I just finish writing my first F# program. Functionality wise the code works the way I wanted, but not sure if the code is efficient. I would much appreciate if someone could review the code for me and point out the areas where the code can be improved.

Thanks
Sudaly

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.IO.Pipes
open System.Text
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Runtime.Serialization


[<DataContract>] 
type Quote = { 
    [<field: DataMember(Name="securityIdentifier") >] 
    RicCode:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name="madeOn") >] 
    MadeOn:DateTime
    [<field: DataMember(Name="closePrice") >] 
    Price:float 
    }

let m_cache = new Dictionary<string, Quote>() 

let ParseQuoteString (quoteString:string) = 
    let data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(quoteString)
    let stream = new MemoryStream() 
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); 
    stream.Position <- 0L 
    let ser = Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<Quote array>) 
    let results:Quote array = ser.ReadObject(stream) :?> Quote array
    results

let RefreshCache quoteList =
    m_cache.Clear()
    quoteList |> Array.iter(fun result->m_cache.Add(result.RicCode, result))


let EstablishConnection() =
    let pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 4)
    let mutable sr = null
    printfn "[F#] NamedPipeServerStream thread created, Wait for a client to connect"
    pipeServer.WaitForConnection()
    printfn "[F#] Client connected."
    try
        // Stream for the request. 
        sr <- new StreamReader(pipeServer)
    with
    | _ as e -> printfn "[F#]ERROR: %s" e.Message
    sr


while true do
    let sr = EstablishConnection()
    // Read request from the stream.
    printfn "[F#] Ready to Receive data"

    sr.ReadLine()  
    |>  ParseQuoteString  
    |>  RefreshCache

    printfn "[F#]Quot Size, %d" m_cache.Count
    let quot = m_cache.["MSFT.OQ"]
    printfn "[F#]RIC: %s" quot.RicCode
    printfn "[F#]MadeOn: %s" (String.Format("{0:T}",quot.MadeOn))
    printfn "[F#]Price: %f" quot.Price
```

Comment: You might want to explain what the code is intended to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you should try using immutable data types and avoid imperative constructs such as global variables and imperative loops - although using them in F# is fine in many cases, they should be used only when there is a good reason for doing so. Here are a couple of examples where you could use functional approach:

---

First of all, to make the code more functional, you should avoid using global mutable cache. Instead, your `RefreshCache` function should return the data as the result (preferably using some functional data structure, such as F# `Map` type):

```
let PopulateCache quoteList = 
  quoteList 
  // Generate a sequence of tuples containing key and value 
  |> Seq.map (fun result -> result.RicCode, result)
  // Turn the sequence into an F# immutable map (replacement for hashtable)
  |> Map.ofSeq
```

The code that uses it would be changed like this:

```
let cache = 
  sr.ReadLine()   
  |>  ParseQuoteString   
  |>  PopulateCache

printfn "[F#]Quot Size, %d" m_cache.Count 
let quot = m_cache.["MSFT.OQ"] 
// The rest of the sample stays the same
```

---

In the `EstablishConnection` function, you definitely don't need to declare a mutable variable `sr`, because in case of an exception, the function will return `null`. I would instead use `option` type to make sure that this case is handled:

```
let EstablishConnection() = 
    let pipeServer = 
      new NamedPipeServerStream("testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 4) 
    printfn "[F#] NamedPipeServerStream thread created..." 
    pipeServer.WaitForConnection() 
    printfn "[F#] Client connected." 
    try // Wrap the result in 'Some' to denote success
        Some(new StreamReader(pipeServer))
    with e -> 
        printfn "[F#]ERROR: %s" e.Message 
        // Return 'None' to denote a failure
        None
```

The main loop can be written using a recursive function that stops when `EstablishConnection` fails:

```
let rec loop() =
  match EstablishConnection() with
  | Some(conn) ->
      printfn "[F#] Ready to Receive data"
      // rest of the code
      loop() // continue looping
  | _ -> () // Quit
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a couple thoughts...

You probably want a 'use' rather than a 'let' in a few places, as I think some of the objects in the program are `IDisposable`.

You may consider wrapping the `EstablishConnection` method and the final while loop in async blocks (and make other minor changes), so that e.g. you can wait asynchronously for connections without blocking a thread.

Comment: Thank you for your comments Brian, I’ll make those changes you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance it is written in imperative style rather than functional style, which does make sense given that most of the program involves side effects (i.e. I/O).  Line for line, it almost looks like a C# program.

Given the amount of I/O that is taking place, I don't know that there is much you can do to this particular program to make it more of a functional style of coding.