# Converting C# code to F# (if statement)

Tags: c#, .net, f#, c#-to-f#

I'd like to know how to convert this code **line by line** from C# to F#. I am not looking to use any kind of F#'s idioms or something of the like. I am trying to understand how to **map directly** C#'s constructs to F#.

Here is the C# code:

```
//requires l.Length > 0
int GetMinimumValue(List<int> l) {
    int minVal = l[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < l.Length; ++i) {
        if (l[i] > minValue) {
            minVal = l[i];
        }
    }

    return minVal;
}
```

And here is my F# attempt:

```
let getMinValue (l : int list) =
    let minVal = l.Head

    for i = 0 to (l.Length-1) do
        if (l.Item(i) > minVal) then
            minVal = col.Item(i)

    minVal
```

Now, this ain't working. The problem seems to be related with the `minVal = col.Item(i)` line:

```
This expression was expected to have type     unit     but here has type     bool
```

What is the problem, really?

Comment: While I can't speak directly to your question, asking how to convert from procedural/OO code to functional code **line by line** is not even guaranteed to be possible. I understand the motivation to move slowly from one to the other in order to gain greater understanding, but outright excluding any "F# idioms" is a poor choice.

Comment: I just want to know if is possible. That's all.

Comment: This is perfectly possible, so what's the worry?  See JaredPar's answer.

Comment: It's like saying "I want to learn spanish, but I'll start by writing english words using the spanish alphabet".

Comment: Well, that'll be my problem. I don't get why every one has to go crazy about it.

Comment: @mquander: Yes, in this instance it is. In other instances, it may not be. The point I was trying to make is that it's not always (or even more often than not) the best way to go about it.

Comment: @devoured: I don't see anyone going crazy here, I'm just saying that it's silly to say you want to write something from a functional programming approach by using idioms and practices from another programming model and actively saying "I don't want to use any F# idioms", when they could very well make the code clearer or more concise, or even make the language and the paradigm make more sense to you. This is called learning.

Comment: You might also be interested in this question [My First F# program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877542/my-first-f-program).

Comment: FWIW, the entirety of the "not what you asked" but much shorter idiomatic F# translation would be `let getMinValue = Seq.min`

Comment: Well, his version isn't idiomatic C#, either; that would be `l.Min()`.

Comment: @JoelMueller: I would upvote but I think this `getMinValue` function actually computes the *max* value! :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to convert it line by line then try the following

```
let getMinValue (l:System.Collections.Generic.List<int>) =
  let mutable min = l.Item(0)
  for i = 0 to (l.Count-1) do
    if l.Item(i) < min then min <- l.Item(i)
  min
```

Now as to why you're getting that particular error.  Take a look at the following line

```
minVal = col.Item(i)
```

In F# this is not an assignment but a comparison.  So this is an expression which produces a bool value but inside the `for` loop all expressions must be `void`/`unit` returning.  Hence you receive an error.

Assignment in F# has at least 2 forms that I am aware of.

```
// Assigning to a mutable value
let mutable v1 = 42
v1 <- 13

// Assigning to a ref cell
let v1 = ref 0
v1 := 42
```

And of course, you should absolutely read Brian's article on this subject.  It's very detailed and goes over many of the finer points on translating between the two languages

- http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!725.entry

Comment: Every time I want to have a mutable variable, should I use the mutable keyword?

Comment: @devoured, that's one approach.  Another is to use ref and cells.  Typically though i use mutable vs. a ref unless I need to capture the value in a lambda (mutable + lambda is not allowed).

Comment: That's what it means... Term "variable", just like in maths, is misleading, if you're used to C or BASIC. In maths, variables don't change. If `x` is 3, then that's what it is; in maths, `x = x + 1` is a nonsense, a contradiction. And so it is in most functional languages. Mutable variables bend the rules, and bring you back a bit to the imperative world. However, if you want to write imperative-style, why even bother with the nightmare that is F#? It would be like trying to shave with a lawnmower - sure you can do it, but while they're great with grass, there are better choices for stubble.

Comment: @Amadan: "...like trying to shave with a lawmower" is fantastic. That's a keeper.

Comment: @Amadan: additionally, that's why I always liked when they were referred to (in math) as "unknowns" rather than "variables", as the obvious inference about something labled as a "variable" is that it's...variable.

Comment: You can replace all the `col.Item(i)` calls with `col.[i]` and get the same result...

Comment: "trying to shave with a lawmower" That's what I feel every time I use imperative language because non-technical reasons

Answer (score 6):

There are a few problems with your literal translation.  First of all, there's the immediate problem which causes the compiler error: as others have noted, let bindings are immutable by default.  However, there's at least one other big problem: `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` is very different from F#'s `'t list`.  The BCL type is a mutable list backed by an array, which provides constant time random access to elements; the F# type is an immutable singly linked list, so accessing the nth element takes O(n) time.  If you insist on doing expression-by-expression translation, you may find [this blog post by Brian](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!725.entry) valuable.

I'd strongly recommend that you follow others' advice and try to acclimate yourself to thinking in idiomatic F# rather than literally translating C#.  Here are some ways to write some related functions in F#:

```
// Given an F# list, find the minimum element:
let rec getMinList l =
| [] -> failwith "Can't take the minimum of an empty list"
| [x] -> x
| x::xs ->
    let minRest = getMin xs
    min x minRest
```

Note that this works on lists of any element type (with the caveat that the element type needs to be `comparable` from F#'s perspective or the application of the function will cause a compile-time error).  If you want a version which will work on any type of sequence instead of just on lists, you could base it on the `Seq.reduce` function, which applies the function supplied as its first argument to each pair of elements in a sequence until a single value remains.

```
let getMin s = Seq.reduce min s
```

Or best of all, you can use the built-in `Seq.min` function, which is equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: `=` is not (mutable) assignment in F#.

Question: Do you really mean `col`?

Suggestions: Try to write this with NO assignments. There is recursion and built-in functions at your disposal :-)

Answer (score 4):

You should read

[What does this C# code look like in F#? (part one: expressions and statements)](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!725.entry)

I am disappointed that none of the other answers already linked it, because people ask the 'how to convert C# to F#' question a lot, and I have posted this answer link a lot, and by now some of the other answerers should know this :)

Comment: I just added it to my answer.  Please forgive my tardiness :)

Comment: And JaredPar has added it to his, too.  Are you happy now?  :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the most literal translation possible:

```
let getMinimumValue (l: List<int>) =
  let mutable minVal = l.[0]

  for i=0 to l.Length-1 do
    if l.[i] > minVal then
      minVal <- l.[i]

  minVal
```